# Dynamic route for catalog

Tags: regex, zend-framework, routes

I have this route

```
routes.catalog.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.catalog.route = "(a|a-b|b|c|d|d-a|d-b)(.*)"
routes.catalog.defaults.controller = "category"
routes.catalog.defaults.action = "index"
```

This match correctly with:

```
http://www.example.com/a
http://www.example.com/a/some-param/2
```

but badly with:

```
http://www.example.com/ab
```

Which regex route exclude this case?

Something with slash before whateever (.*) like

```
"(a|a-b|b|c|d|d-a|d-b)(/)(.*)"
```

does not works.

Comment: (a|ab|a-b|b|c|d|d-a|d-b)(.*)

Comment: I guess you need `"^(a|a-b|b|c|d|d-a|d-b)(/.*)?$"` or something like this.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yes it is correct. If you will answer, I will mark it.

Comment: @tomasr Posted with a bit of an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
routes.catalog.route = "^(a|a-b|b|c|d|d-a|d-b)(/.*)?$"
```

The `(/.*)?` part matches 1 or 0 occurrences (i.e. it is optional) of `/` char followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars. That means, after your alternations (`a`, `a-b`, etc.) there must be `/` (followed with anything) or end of string (`$`).

To make it more compact and efficient, you may "shrink" it a bit like

```
"^(d(?:-[ab])?|a(?:-b)?|[bc])(/.*)?$"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/84FSbo/1/). However, if you think the readability suffers greatly, you may still use the expression above.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(d(?:-[ab])?|` - `d` optionally followed with `-a` or `-b` or
- `a(?:-b)?|` - `a` optionally followed with `-b`
- `[bc])` - `b` or `c`
- `(/.*)?` - an optional Group 2 matching `/` and any 0+ chars up to the
- `$`  - end of string.